# pgrouting 2.0 on qgis cannot create route

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I am trying to create a network using pgrouting and PostGIS.

I was initially using OS Open Roads data but even when I follow this tutorial (https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/) and the same data set all i get is the following;

The issue is that when I now attempt to run the route nothing happens, I am using the suggested SQL;

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, geom
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM network.publictransport',
    1, 3000, false, false
  ) as di
  JOIN network.publictransport pt
  ON di.id2 = pt.id ;
```

But, when I execute nothing happens, I do not get an error nor is it loading it just returns 0 columns instead of them being populated.

Comment: Do you get some result without the  `JOIN`?

Comment: I don't sadly but without the join it wouldnt have both the lines and the nodes would I?